# How to open a new Tkinter window in a while loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

### How do I make a new Tkinter window in a while loop?

Tkinter is kind of new to me, so I would like some easy explanations. I would like it to open a Tkinter window in a while loop. Basically, a user says yes to a question, then a new window pops up, and it will ask the question again, and it should pop up again etc...
I have some "code" that would basically say what I mean. All of the other questions out there did not really work for me.
im stupid and didnt include code

```
#import modules
import time
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from playsound import playsound
from threading import Thread

win = Tk()

win.geometry("900x350")

def lift_window():
   win.lift()
   win.after(1000, lift_window)

def sound_play():
    playsound('a sound')

while True:
   start = input("make new window? (y/n): ")
   if start == "y":
      Label(win, text="new window!", font=('Aerial 16 italic')).place(x=5, y=140)

      Thread(target = lift_window).start()
      Thread(target = sound_play).start()

      lift_window()
      win.mainloop()
   elif start == "n":
      print("ok")
      sys.exit()
```

Some error messages I get were

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
```

But that is all.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error means that you are trying to access the label after it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is worded rather poorly. The "application" it speaks of is just the `Tk` instance that `win` points to. It's destroyed when you close the window, so you need to make a new one each time through the loop.

```
while True:
    start = input("make new window? (y/n): ")
    if start == "y":
        win = Tk()
        win.geometry("900x350")
        Label(win, text="new window!", font=('Aerial 16 italic')).place(x=5, y=140)
        win.mainloop()
```

Note that `win` being destroyed will also affect the `win.lift` and `win.after` calls in `lift_window`. I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do there (you call `lift_window` twice, once from a new thread, and each call sets a timer to call it again?), so I can't comment on how to fix that part.